`scipy.optimize.minimize` gives different results on GCP and Mac
SciPy's minimize() gives different results on different machines:
sp.optimize.minimize(cost_function, x_init, bounds=x_bounds, args=args_in, method='SLSQP', options={'maxiter': sim_config['maxiter'], 'disp': False})

I have made sure that the version on python installed on GCP and Mac is same and the version of pandas, numpy and scipy is same as well.
In spite of this, the outputs differ (though very little).

How much do they differ?

What are the respective architectures?

The problem is that there are a long list of things that can cause this difference. For example, if the two systems were built against a different BLAS library, that can in turn cause your cost function to return a slightly different result. If your cost function returns a slightly different result for any input, then minimize will try a slightly different x value next time, and the difference will amplify over time.

In order to figure out what's causing the change in the result, you need to change one variable at a time. Right now, you're changing the operating system, the compiler, the BLAS library (maybe - depends on your version of OSX) and the architecture (maybe) all at once. No way to say which one of those is the cause of the problem without trying intermediate steps that have only one variable changed.

@NickODell
python version and the version of all the libraries( including BLAS library)installed on both the environments is same. though the compiler version is different - its  Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30) for the mac and gcp - GCC 11.4.0

i guess the scipy library is working differently for windows , mac and Linux(GCP)
